# How to preview images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working whit `reactjs` to preview selected images in front. I have three image tags so I want to choose three images and show them in three different `img tag` for preview. but now when I choose `photo2` it previews it in `photo1`. also the same as  `photo3`.

any help would be appreciated.

this is the image:

[image]

These are my functions:

```
const [picture1, setPicture1] = useState(null);
const [picture2, setPicture2] = useState(null);
const [picture3, setPicture3] = useState(null);
const [imgData1, setImgData1] = useState(data?.avatar?.url || null);
const [imgData2, setImgData2] = useState(data?.avatar?.url || null);
const [imgData3, setImgData3] = useState(data?.avatar?.url || null);

const onChangePicture1 = e => {
  if (e.target.files[0]) {
    setPicture1(e.target.files[0]);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      setImgData1(reader.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  }
};
const onChangePicture2 = e => {
  if (e.target.files[0]) {
    setPicture2(e.target.files[0]);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      setImgData2(reader.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  }
};
const onChangePicture3 = e => {
  if (e.target.files[0]) {
    setPicture3(e.target.files[0]);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      setImgData3(reader.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  }
};
```

This is my code:

```
<div className="mt-6 grid sm:grid-cols-1 sm:gap-1 md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-3 lg:grid-cols-3 lg:gap-3">
    {imgData1 === null ? (
      <File name="photo1" label={"Photo1"} onChange={onChangePicture1} />
    ) : (
      <div className="sm:block">
        <label
          htmlFor="cover-photo"
          className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
        >
          Photo 1
        </label>
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="w-full">
            <div className="justify-center px-2 pt-2 pb-2 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md text-center">
              <img
                className="-mb-5 w-full h-28 object-cover"
                src={imgData1}
              />

              <label
                htmlFor="file-upload"
                className="p-0.5 relative cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 "
              >
                <span className="text-3xl">+</span>
                <input
                  id="file-upload"
                  name="file-upload"
                  type="file"
                  onChange={onChangePicture1}
                  className="sr-only"
                />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
    {imgData2 === null ? (
      <File name="photo2" label={"Photo2"} onChange={onChangePicture2} />
    ) : (
      <div className="sm:block">
        <label
          htmlFor="cover-photo"
          className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
        >
          Photo 2
        </label>
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="w-full">
            <div className="justify-center px-2 pt-2 pb-2 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md text-center">
              <img
                className="-mb-5 w-full h-28 object-cover"
                src={imgData2}
              />

              <label
                htmlFor="file-upload"
                className="p-0.5 relative cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 "
              >
                <span className="text-3xl">+</span>
                <input
                  id="file-upload"
                  name="file-upload"
                  type="file"
                  onChange={onChangePicture2}
                  className="sr-only"
                />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
    {imgData3 === null ? (
      <File name="photo3" label={"Photo3"} onChange={onChangePicture3} />
    ) : (
      <div className="sm:block">
        <label
          htmlFor="cover-photo"
          className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
        >
          Photo 3
        </label>
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="w-full">
            <div className="justify-center px-2 pt-2 pb-2 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md text-center">
              <img
                className="-mb-5 w-full h-28 object-cover"
                src={imgData3}
              />

              <label
                htmlFor="file-upload"
                className="p-0.5 relative cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 "
              >
                <span className="text-3xl">+</span>
                <input
                  id="file-upload"
                  name="file-upload"
                  type="file"
                  onChange={onChangePicture3}
                  className="sr-only"
                />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same id on each file input `id="file-upload"`, and you wrap all of them with a label with `htmlFor="file-upload"`, so regardless of which button you click, you always trigger the first one.

Since your label wraps the `input`, you do not need to use the `htmlFor` property, and skipping it will cause each label to trigger its corresponding `input`. But it is better to just fix the `id` values and the relevant `htmlFor` props.

---

In general, though

- use unique `id` attributes throughout the page
- use the `for` attribute (*with the unique `id`s*) to maintain accessibility improvements.

Answer (score 1):

try [URL.createObjectUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method

in react

```
export default function MyApp() {
  const [previewUrl, setPreviewUrl] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => {
        const file = e.target.files?.[0];

        if (file) {
          setPreviewUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
        }
      }} />
      {previewUrl && (
        <img src={previewUrl} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Did not work, but anyway, I used your code in another place, because it is more simple than what I used.